# Silverlight 3: Get value for current XAML filename

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0

I am wanting to simply get the current XAML filename so I can make a decision in a user control. Any ideas on where this value lives in Silverlight 3?

For example:

```
if (currentPage == "home")  
    homeLink.foreground = "white"  
elseif (cuurentPage == "settings")  
    settingsLink.foreground = "white"
```

Comment: If you can't find an answer, you could add a dependency property to the user control, and set it in each page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't undestand your question, but **this.GetType().Name** should give you what you need.

Comment: I think this is my answer. Thanks for the input!       

     NavigationService nav = new NavigationService();
     string currentPage = nav.Source.Host;